# NSTextFinder and Regular Expression search

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nstextview

Is it possible to add Regular Expression searching to the `NSTextFinder` bar in OS X Lion's `NSTextView`?

I've read through the documentation but I can't find any hooks which would allow this.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Mountain Lion the Search Bar allows so called "patterns" out of the box. There's a search option "Insert Pattern". So users can search for "Any Characters" or "Digits"...

[image]

This works by using **NSDataDetector** and it is possible to define custom DataDetectors. But to be honest, I have no clue on how to add them to the list of available detectors. The documentation is indeed quite rare about this.

Comment: I'm already using and aware of that feature, I think it was added to OS X 10.7. I didn't know you could provide custom data detectors... will have to look into that. My app is targeted at programmers however, and they will want to use proper regex patterns.